# Android shared library sum of sections size is greater than shared lib size

Tags: android, c, gcc, shared-libraries, elf

In Android, if I analyse a shared library using objdump tool, I observe the following:

sum of the section sizes in the shared library is less than the binary file size. Which is understandable as,
Binary size = ELF header size + Program header size + section size + section header size.

However for another shared library sum of section sizes is greater than the shared library file size itself! This seems to be very surprising. Is there any case where this can happen?

Commands used:
To capture the section sizes :
prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/arm-eabi/bin/objdump -x

To calculate file size of the shared library :
ls -l

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the actual objdump output (why?), so I'm only guessing, but this is probably because of the `.bss` section.

`.bss` contains all of the static or global variables that are not explicitly initialized when the program starts. Because they have no initial value there is no need for the binary to contain any actual values. The section is just there as a placeholder. It will have meta-data (size, location, symbol offsets), but no actual data.

When you load a program into memory, to run it, there's no need to actually load anything from the file, but the ELF loader will reserve the proper amount of memory in the right place, and it is the job of the program to zero-initialize that memory (typically the `crt1.o` code does that).

Here is an example:

```
objdump -x /bin/bash
....
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
....
 24 .data         00008360  00000000006db620  00000000006db620  000db620  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .bss          00005a48  00000000006e3980  00000000006e3980  000e3980  2**5
                  ALLOC
 26 .gnu_debuglink 0000000c  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000e3980  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

There are three different kinds of section here:

- `.data` is a "normal" section with `CONTENTS`, `ALLOC` and `LOAD` flags set.
- `.bss` has no real data to store or load, so it only has `ALLOC`.
- `.gnu_debuglink` is not for the running program at all; it has no `VMA` or `LMA` set, and has no `ALLOC` or `LOAD` flags set, although it does have real `CONTENTS` (for linking/debugging purposes)